# spring data mongodb 1.8.x configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

```
<mongo:db-factory client-uri="mongodb://${mongo.config.username}:${mongo.config.password}@${mongo.config.replica.set.address}/${mongo.config.database}?replicaSet=${mongo.config.replica.set.name}" />

<bean id="secondaryPreferredReadPreference" class="com.mongodb.TaggableReadPreference.SecondaryPreferredReadPreference"></bean>

<bean id="mongoOperations" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory"/>
    <property name="readPreference" ref="secondaryPreferredReadPreference" />
</bean>
```

This configuration for spring-data-mongodb1.8.x and mongodb3.0's replicaSet is OK. But I don't know how to config ohter options, like connection pool size....